# How to download a file in javascript or jquery from a webmethod that is in byte[]?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, c#-4.0

I am having problems to download an excel file using jquery. I have read in some forums that this is not possible using ajax and in some they say that you can achieve this sending the results to an iframe. So far I have not been able to solve my problem.

Technical details:
I generate a query to a database with some parameters, a webservice performs this query and returns an excel file generated in openxml and returns the bytes.
I am using asp.net 4.0. 
If I use the regular webcontrols and ajax the file is downloaded with no problem if in the update panel I set the triggers to asp:postbacktrigger to the button control.

I am trying to achieve the same results using only jqueryUi controls and jquery.

In the server side I have two methods:

**ExportToExcel:**
This method receives the parameters to call a rest webservice that returns the excelfile.

**SendExcelFileByBytes**
This one is the method that returns the file in the request.

Here is the C# code:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static void ExportToExcel(List<int> status, List<Guid> companyId, List<DateTime> dateFrom, List<DateTime> dateTo, bool isGroupedByStore)
    {
        ReconciliationModule server = new ReconciliationModule(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["serviceNamespace"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACSHostUrl"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["scopeAddress"]);
        SummaryReport summaryReport = new SummaryReport();

        List<Tuple<Guid, DateTime, DateTime, int>> parameters = new List<Tuple<Guid, DateTime, DateTime, int>>();

        for (int i = 0; i < dateTo.Count; i++)
        {
            parameters.Add(new Tuple<Guid, DateTime, DateTime, int>(
                companyId[i],
                dateFrom[i],
                dateTo[i],
                status[i]
            ));
        }

        byte[] x = server.GetSummaryReportInExcel(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userName"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["pwdOrSymmetricKey"], bool.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["isSymmetricKey"]), isGroupedByStore, parameters);

        SendExcelFileByBytes(x);
    }

    private static void SendExcelFileByBytes(byte[] x)
    {
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"SummaryReport.xlsx\"");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/force-download");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/download");
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";//excel file
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(x);
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
    }
```

For the jscript my callAjaxFunction is failing and returning a 200 OK message with the results in the responseText. So in the function that is performed when something fails i am showing the responseText in a table.
If someone can help me to do this in a better way it will be greatly appreciated.
And here is the jscript code:

```
//Executes Ajax Calls using json as data type
function callAjax(callType, urlAddress, dataToSend, fnSucceeded, fnFailed) {
    $.ajax({
        type: callType,
        url: urlAddress,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: "json",
        success: fnSucceeded,
        error: fnFailed
    });
}

//TODO: This function is the one i need to correct
function getSummaryReportInExcel() {

    ShowLoader('#reconciliation');
    var isGroupedByStore = new Boolean($('#CompanyTypes :checkbox').attr('checked'));
    var stat = getStatus();
    var status = new Array();
    var companyId = new Array();
    var dateFrom = new Array();
    var dateTo = new Array();
    var companiesToSearch = $('#CompanyConfigurations :checkbox:checked');

    //populating the parameters
    $(companiesToSearch).each(function (i, currentCompany) {
        status.push(stat);
        companyId.push($(currentCompany).select('checkbox').attr('value'));
        dateFrom.push($(currentCompany).parents().find('td:eq(2) :input').attr('value'));
        dateTo.push($(currentCompany).parents().find('td:eq(3) :input').attr('value'));
    });

    var data = "{ status : " + JSON.stringify(status) + ", companyId : " +  JSON.stringify(companyId) + ", dateFrom : " +  JSON.stringify(dateFrom) + ", dateTo : " +  JSON.stringify(dateTo) + ", isGroupedByStore : " + isGroupedByStore + " }";

    alert(data);

    callAjax(
        "POST", "UIJquery.aspx/ExportToExcel",
        data,
        //is not entering here
        function () {
            alert('Hola' + result.toString());

            //header.
            HideLoader();
        },
        //AjaxFailed
        function (result) {
            //alert(concatObject( result));
            $('#SearchResults').append(concatObject(result));
            //var iFrame = "<iframe src=" + result.responseText + "></iframe>";


            $('#IResults').html(result.responseText);
            //window.open(result.responseText, 'Download');
            HideLoader();
            //alert(concatObject(result));
        }
    );
}
```

Here is what i see in the Developer tools in google chrome

```
HeadersPreviewResponseTiming
Request URL:http://localhost:53144/UIJquery.aspx/ExportToExcel
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:216
Content-Type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host:localhost:53144
Origin:http://localhost:53144
Referer:http://localhost:53144/UIJQuery.aspx
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.83 Safari/535.11
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Request Payload
{ status : [15,15], companyId : ["15afbacb-5c0c-4402-a5af-0f5a53221bbb","041d6a48-35ca-4d55-97ec-4fd5f4bdd11f"], dateFrom : ["11/06/2011","11/06/2011"], dateTo : ["11/12/2011","11/12/2011"], isGroupedByStore : true }
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:private, max-age=0
Connection:Close
Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="SummaryReport.xlsx"
Content-Type:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
Date:Wed, 28 Mar 2012 18:22:32 GMT
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319
```

Any suggestions or better ways to do it let me know thanks.

Comment: Whats the point of getting a binary file in jQuery? Just construct the url that will result in the file download and send the brwoser to it (window.location).

Comment: Can you give me an example? I am new to the web thanks.

Comment: in your CallAjax, your telling jQuery to expect a JSON string back which fails when it gets back the binary from your webservice. There is no 'binary' or 'byte' datatype in jQuery.ajax, the closest your going to get is 'text' which is not going to work well with binary output.

Comment: Just ran your payload JSON through JSONlint http://jsonlint.com/ and its getting a parse error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadExcelFile(url, dataToSend) {
   url += '?';
   for(var k in dataToSend) {
      url += k + '=' + encodeURIComponent(dataTosend[k]) + '&';
      }
   window.location = url;
   }
</script>
```

this will take the base url as first argument, and an object containing the parameters as a second, construct a full url from this and redirect the browser to it... eg

```
downloadExcelFile('http://www.example.com/myWebservice/downloadExcel.aspx', {
   param1: 'value1',
   param2: 'value2'
   });
```

the browser in this case will be redirected to

```
http://www.example.com/myWebservice/downloadExcel.aspx?param1=value1&param2=value2&
```

Comment: I solve this problem using this solution: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55488/File-Download-Using-JavaScript